# Eclipse - annoying error when editing css files

Tags: css, eclipse

Each time I edit a css file in Eclipse, I get this error. It really keeps me from doing my work, because it pops up almost after each character.

> Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key css2.stylesheet-def.description

I would like to disable the parsing for css in order to not get this error anymore, but I didn't find how. Can you give me any tip on how to solve this issue ?

Comment: I believe this would be some sort of CSS validator, which can probably be found in `Window > Preferences > Validation` but I am not sure which one. I suppose you could test this theory out by selecting the `Suspend all validators` in the `validation` window.

Comment: It's not related to validation, but to the french locale. I launched eclipse in English, and I don't have the problem.

Comment: I commented on the bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=419986 , I'm not able to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like Eclipse bug [419986](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=419986) which says it because of missing translations in the CSS property files.

The bug report suggests deleting the localization plugin (such as `org.eclipse.wst.css.core.nl_fr_4.3.0.jar` works around the problem).

Comment: Do you have any `org.eclipse.wst.css.core.nl_*` plugin?

Comment: The localizations seem to be bundled differently in different Eclipse releases.

Comment: Finally, I found the file in C:\Users\%username%\.eclipse\org.eclipse.platform_4.3.0_920333535_win32_win32_x86_64\plugins. I deleted it as recommended in the bugtracker's comments. This solved the problem.